# IIS 6 URL Rewrtting for multiple locations from Query String

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I have two websites urls which are running in IIS 6, pointed to the same web.config file.

(IIS 6 dont have IIS 7 URL rewriting available) so they use 3rdparty tool to do the url rewriting,

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/2600-Using-UrlRewriting-to-redirect-domain

so what i want to do is

if someone type the following in the browser (website 1)

y.xxx.com/something ->

they need to be redirected to

http://y.xxx.com/per/found/

but if they type the second domain  (website 2 still using the same web.config file, same folder)

zzz.com

they need to stay where they are.

I try to did this but didnt work

```
<add name="just-a-name-which-one"  
   redirect="Domain" 
   ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
   virtualUrl="http://xxx.com/(.*)"   
redirectMode="Permanent" 
destinationUrl="http://xxx.com/something/" 
/>
```

how can achieve this functionality ? using IIS-6 ..

Comment: In the virtualUrl, can you use a negative lookahead assertion to filter on the domain name?

For example: `(?!xxx\.com)`

Also, I noticed that you mentioned a 3-part domain (y.xxx.com), but the virtualUrl only has a 2-part name (xxx.com)